# Vertical sum in a given binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, tree

I'm working on [this problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertical-sum-in-a-given-binary-tree/),

**Problem statement**,

> Given a Binary Tree, find vertical sum of the nodes that are in same vertical line. Print all sums through different vertical lines.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>      1
>    /   \
>   2      3
>  / \    / \
> 4   5  6   7
> ```
>
> The tree has 5 vertical lines
>
> - Vertical-Line-1 has only one node 4 => vertical sum is 4
> - Vertical-Line-2: has only one node 2=> vertical sum is 2
> - Vertical-Line-3: has three nodes: 1,5,6 => vertical sum is 1+5+6 = 12
> - Vertical-Line-4: has only one node 3 => vertical sum is 3
> - Vertical-Line-5: has only one node 7 => vertical sum is 7
>
> So expected output is 4, 2, 12, 3 and 7

I’m wondering if there is a way to not write recursive code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def vertical_traverse(self, level):
        stack = []
        result = defaultdict(list) # key: level, value: list of node identifier
        stack.append((self,level))
        while len(stack) > 0:
            node, level = stack.pop(-1)
            result[level].append(node.value)
            if node.left:
                stack.append((node.left, level-1))
            if node.right:
                stack.append((node.right, level+1))
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(4, None, None), TreeNode(5, None, None)), TreeNode(3, TreeNode(6, None, None), TreeNode(7, None, None)))
    result = root.vertical_traverse(0)
    for k,v in result.items():
        print k, sum(v)
```

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, for sure, posted the question to make it  more self contained.

Comment: (`posted the question` please use a block quote to make parts stand out that are "not your own" (attribution by providing a link is sufficient in my book)) So, the nodes of a vertical line have the same difference between left and right links followed to get from the root to each node.

Comment: `I am wondering if there is a way to not write recursive code` With a data structure defined and represented recursively: _Why_?

Comment: @greybeard, for the purpose of trying to see if writing in iterative way is faster than recursive way. For your comments, `With a data structure defined and represented recursively`, I do not quite get it, what data structure do you mean -- `TreeNode`?

Comment: @greybeard, for your comments -- ` please use a block quote to make parts stand out that are "not your own" `, the complete non-recursive version of code is my own. I post an external link since I want to show how other people is doing recursive way for the problem. if you have any thoughts on my original question, it will be great.